# How to start Apache server in Linux

Tags: linux, apache, unix

I have created a new httpd.conf file now i want my Apache to use that conf file and get start . But that is not working for me . When i am trying to start the Apache i am getting error

```
./apachectl -k start
httpd: Could not open configuration file /usr/local/install/apache/conf/httpd.conf: No such file or directory
```

my new conf file is at

```
/home/<user>/conf/httpd.conf
```

I am unable to understand where i have do to the changes to use this http.conf

Comment: `# ln -sv /home/<user>/conf/httpd.conf /usr/local/install/apache/conf/httpd.conf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install apache. For ArchLinux follow [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apache_HTTP_Server#Installation) instalaltion guide.

Then start the service just running this command ad administrator:

```
sudo systemctl start httpd.service
```

Check if it is working with:

```
sudo systemctl status httpd.service
```

Comment: What does this (accepted) answer has to do with the question? Question is about location of conf file not about starting apache...

Answer (score 0):

`apachectl -f /home/<user>/conf/httpd.conf`